# How do I change the text color of the inline breakpoint settings?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I use a dark theme, and I have my code "peek" background set to a dark color as well.

In VS2017, instead of the older dialog window you'd get when modifying a breakpoint, you get the settings inline instead, similar to how the "peek" bits look.

However, I can't find a way to change the text color of this area, so now I am trying to squint at dark grey text on a dark purple background. It seems as though the "peek" background color is shared with the breakpoint settings.

Is it possible to change this color?

Here's an image to show you what I mean:

[image]

Comment: its even worse here; white characters on white background cant even see the combo boxes, blue text is still blue. Have you found the solution?

Comment: @ufosnowcat I have not

Comment: Thanks for sharing the bit about "peek" -- changing peek background seems a suitable workaround for me.